# convert a json response object to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a collection of locations in mongodb, I wrote a simple api to get the locations, following is the code:

```
app.get('/onlyfields', (req, res) => {
   
      const promise1 = onlyfields.find({}, {_id:0})
      const promise2 = geopoints.find({}, {locations:1, _id:0})
      Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
        .then(([result1, result2]) => {
          res.send({ fields: result1, rows: result2 })
          console.log(result2)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'Erorr en STATUS2'
          })
        })
    
})
```

The locations data is stored in result2.

the console.log shows the following response:

```
MongoDB Connected
[
  {
    locations: [
      2,
      '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
      '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
      1,
      1.4,
      -73.9837265,
      40.74634171,
      -73.96679688,
      40.76140594,
      8.5,
      0,
      9.3
    ]
  },
  {
    locations: [
      2,
      '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
      '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
      1,
      1.4,
      -73.9837265,
      40.74634171,
      -73.96679688,
      40.76140594,
      8.5,
      0,
      9.3
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to modify the result2 data to the following format, whaich is an array of arrays:

```
[
   [
      2,
      '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
      '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
      1,
      1.4,
      -73.9837265,
      40.74634171,
      -73.96679688,
      40.76140594,
      8.5,
      0,
      9.3
    ]
  ,
   [
      2,
      '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
      '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
      1,
      1.4,
      -73.9837265,
      40.74634171,
      -73.96679688,
      40.76140594,
      8.5,
      0,
      9.3
    ]

]
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map each of the result's `location` array, e.g.

```
function flatten(data) {
    return data.map(currEntry => currEntry.locations)
}
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        locations: [
            2,
            '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
            '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
            1,
            1.4,
            -73.9837265,
            40.74634171,
            -73.96679688,
            40.76140594,
            8.5,
            0,
            9.3
        ]
    },
    {
        locations: [
            2,
            '2015-01-15 14:00:41 +00:00',
            '2015-01-15 14:11:18 +00:00',
            1,
            1.4,
            -73.9837265,
            40.74634171,
            -73.96679688,
            40.76140594,
            8.5,
            0,
            9.3
        ]
    }
];

function flatten(data) {
    return data.map(currEntry => currEntry.locations)
}

console.log(flatten(data))
```